# org-mode table exports centered - change to left?

Tags: org-export, org-table

I'm exporting a simple org-table through LaTeX to PDF:

```
| a | b | c |
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
```

After export with `C-c C-e l o` the PDF contains a centered table, and I'd rather have it on the left (to be clear, I'm referring here to the *table as a whole*, not the positioning of elements in individual cells).

I'm not an expert at LaTeX. I've looked at `:float` and `:placement` in the Org manual [here](http://orgmode.org/manual/LaTeX-specific-attributes.html) and haven't been able to affect the outcome. How could I accomplish this?

Comment: Will adding `#+ATTR_LaTeX: :center nil` before the table do what you need, or do you want to move the table even further to the left?

Comment: @wvxvw You should make that an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`#+ATTR_LaTeX: :center nil` will cancel centering (by default LaTeX tables inherit alignment from the document)

This is how the table would be exported with default settings:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
a & b & c\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
```

This is how it would be exported without centering:

```
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
a & b & c\\
1 & 2 & 3\\
\end{tabular}
```

If you need to move it even further to the left, you could add

```
#+BEGIN_LaTeX
  \hspace{-3cm}
#+END_LaTeX
```

before the table.

Comment: I tried to move the table to the left with the last example, but all I get is the LaTeX string before the table... (command: `$ emacs file.org --batch -f org-latex-export-to-pdf --kill`)

Answer (score 1):

To make it global, applied to all tables, you can also customize this variable

`M-x` `customize-variable` `org-latex-tables-centered`

and look into *options > customize emacs > specific group > org-export-latex* for more.